# Graphs with the property that $f=f^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Ive been working on this question and can't seem to progress,
I know that for a function to have the property $f=f'$ it must be symmetrical about the line $y=x$,I can't find reasoning behind in the general case $g(x)=x-f(x)$ (where $f(x)$ has the property $f=f^{-1}$) , how do I show that there must exist a point such that $g(x)$=$0$?
any help would be appreciated.

> If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is contiuous and $f=f^{-1}$ prove that there is at least one $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = 1/x$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is wrong. You can't extend $\dfrac1x$ to a continuous function on $\mathbb R$. (and e.g. $-\dfrac1x$ would be a counterexample on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$)

The idea of a proof is this: Since $f(x)$ is continuous, then $f(x)-x$ is continuous too. If $f(x)-x\ne0\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\ne x$ everywhere, then $f(x)$ is entirely below or above the $y=x$ line, which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it.